# Add a vertical dash and dash line to a LineChart (mpandroidchart)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart, x-axis

Label done with ValueFormatter.
LineChart with:

```
chart.xAxis.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false)
```

Makes a line to the whole Y Axis.

I need something like that. I think I've tried everything.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LimitLine` and call `enableDashedLine()` to draw the vertical dashed line.

Comment: How set limit of length of LimitLine? As You can see I need dashed line from axis to graph line.

Comment: You can see details in "Limit Lines" section.
https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/

Comment: There are no ability to set length to LimitLine unfortunately. And tail of addition of it to create own Chart with own axis with own limitlines. But thank you